# Sort groups and keep spaces

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for help on a code where the end user hits a button and it sorts the data, but keeps the "groups" together (from columns A through AA) as well as the spaces between tasks.

I've done some research online, but wasn't able to get anything to work, so I don't even have a base code to start from.

Here's some pictures to show what I'm trying to accomplish.

The first image shows the tasks as they may have been entered, but then we assign priorities after all tasks are entered and, as you can see, they're out of order.

[image]

Then I'd like for them to hit that "sort" button on the top left of the image, and it sort the worksheet base upon priority, with 1 being the first task, and going down to the last, but keep the "groups" and the space between tasks, so it ends up looking like this:

[image]

Again, columns affected would be from A through AA (i.e., the data needing to stay together spans between those columns).

I don't know if this is even possible, but any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

EDIT:

I created a thread on ExcelForum so I can post an actual spreadsheet... that post is here: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1362269-sort-groups-and-keep-spaces.html#post5585545

Comment: This is easily accomplished with a pivot table, but it depends on exactly how the "original" data is organized. I say "original" because if the data you've shown IS the original data, then you'll have to re-create the data into a form that can feed a pivot table. After that, the pivot table will allow you to sort and filter exactly how you want.

Comment: Agreed Peter! I'm already doing a Pivot table to help sort who has what tasks (for resource balancing), but I need the actual task list to be in priority order because it's where they are physically manipulating the data in the other columns (not shown). So we're doing Priority 1 before 2, but without having to go to a separate table to look at it, come back here to manipulate it, back to the table, etc. Thanks for the thought though!

Comment: @WaveWalker116 - why is the pivot table with sorting not an option?  IIf the pivot table is not an option then we need more details on what you have tried and what is not working. MHO is that you should just keep this in MS Project which provides this functionality out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Sam, fully agree on MS Project! If only we had the software... haha. I used it at my previous job and it was great. Pivot would "work" but just not as I need it to. I need this information on this task list so we can manipulate data (in columns not shown) rather than going to another tab, looking at priority, back to this tab, make changes, back to the pivot table, refresh, back to this tab, etc. As for the details of what I tried, I did some searching on Google, but couldn't find anything that makes this work. I don't know VBA well enough to write something from scratch, so here I am. lol.

Comment: I edited the original post with a link to ExcelForum where I posted an actual spreadsheet, if that would help.

Comment: @WaveWalker116 - I understand.  
What I suggest then is that you start with the structure of your table and set that up to make things a bit easier.  For example, you may want to add an identifier (such as a WBS ID) to keep the tasks together as a group and then also add the priority to each task. If you do that, then you could just sort the entire thing in place with no VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 spare columns to hold sort order keys.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub sortit()

   Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
   Dim LastRow As Long, r As Long
   Dim p As Integer, n As Long

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
   With ws
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1

        ' use column AB,AC for sort order
        For r = 4 To LastRow
            If .Cells(r, "A") > 0 Then
                p = .Cells(r, "A")
                n = 0
            End If
            n = n + 1
            .Cells(r, "AB") = p
            .Cells(r, "AC") = n
        Next

        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("AB4"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("AC4"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange ws.Range("A4:AC" & LastRow)
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        ' clear columns
        .Columns("AB:AC").Clear
    End With

    MsgBox "Sorted"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks CDP! Some also answered in the ExcelForum thread, so now I have two codes to play with! I love your idea of adding a message box that says "sorted"... I'll use that as well. THANK YOU!!!